# Building AOSP rom: no rules to make target "external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/eap_proxy_qmi.mk"

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod, building

I tried to build an AOSP 7.1.1 ROM for my device (lenovo zuk z1) using device trees from other CM based ROMs.
The build fails after 1 minute with this error:

```
no rules to make target "external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/eap_proxy_qmi.mk"
```

I tried to search on the web and XDA forums, but I couldn't find any help.
I know that building an AOSP rom using CM device trees is quite difficult, but I want to know if there is a chance to do it or I should give up. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
rm -rf external/wpa_supplicant_8
git clone https://github.com/LineageOS/android_external_wpa_supplicant_8.git -b cm-14.1 external/wpa_supplicant_8
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it solved that error, and as I expected I had other similar errors about other trees, I cloned them and I have this error now:

Comment: device/zuk/ham/libaudioamp/audio_amplifier.c:20:10: fatal error: 'platform.h' file not found
#include <platform.h>
     
1 error generated.
build/core/binary.mk:1005: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "/home/mike/DiscoDati/abc/out/target/product/ham/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/audio_amplifier.msm8974_intermediates/audio_amplifier.o" non riuscito
make: *** [/home/mike/DiscoDati/abc/out/target/product/ham/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/audio_amplifier.msm8974_intermediates/audio_amplifier.o] Errore 1

Comment: This is the full build log if it can help https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9vudYbIfwbDNmJzMk5ZQWRwMWc

Comment: Have you fixed? If no, just let me know. I know the fix :P

Comment: Hi, I did not resolve it, I tried to clone many cm trees but it get worst then ever. I tried to look at different manifests of some caf/aosp roms of the oneplusX that has same hw of my zuk z1, to understand which trees to track, but after several tries i gave up